# Reverse the Multi label binarizer in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I have pandas dataframe as

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

# load sample data 
df = pd.DataFrame( {'user_id':['1','1','2','2','2','3'], 'fruits':['banana','orange','orange','apple','banana','mango']})
```

I collect all the fruits for each user using below code -

```
# collect fruits for each user 
transformed_df= df.groupby('user_id').agg({'fruits':lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()

print(transformed_df)
  user_id                   fruits
0       1         [banana, orange]
1       2  [orange, apple, banana]
2       3                  [mango]
```

Once I get this list, I do multilabel-binarizer operation to convert this list into ones or zeroes

```
# perform MultiLabelBinarizer
final_df = transformed_df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(transformed_df.pop('fruits')),columns=mlb.classes_,index=transformed_df.index))

print(final_df)
  user_id  apple  banana  mango  orange
0       1      0       1      0       1
1       2      1       1      0       1
2       3      0       0      1       0
```

Now, I have a requirement wherein, the input dataframe given to me is `final_df` and I need to get back the `transformed_df` which contains the list of `fruits` for each user.

How can I get this `transformed_df` back , given that I have `final_df` as input dataframe?

I am trying to get this working

```
# Trying to get this working
inverse_df = final_df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.inverse_transform(final_df.loc[:, final_df.columns != 'user_id'].as_matrix())))

inverse_df
  user_id  apple  banana  mango  orange       0       1       2
0       1      0       1      0       1  banana  orange    None
1       2      1       1      0       1   apple  banana  orange
2       3      0       0      1       0   mango    None    None
```

But it doesnt give me the list back.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

`inverse_transform()` method should help. Here's the documentation - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.inverse_transform.

Comment: I tried `mlb.inverse_transform(final_df.loc[:, final_df.columns != 'user_id'])` but I got an error saying  `return [tuple(self.classes_.compress(indicators)) for indicators
ValueError: condition must be a 1-d array`

Comment: What does `final_df.loc[:, final_df.columns != 'user_id']` print to?

Comment: it gives me a dataframe with all columns except `user_id`

Comment: `inverse_transform()` expects `array or sparse matrix of shape (n_samples, n_classes). A matrix containing only 1s ands 0s.`. So, as long as these conditions are met, it should not error out. Maybe you can update the question with these codes and errors.

Comment: i have updated the question, will be helpful if you can show me the sample solution for this question.